# Trying to call a smarty plugin (with params) in smarty foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, plugins, recursion, smarty

I'm trying to embed a personal plugin into my smarty TPL files, but I couldn't make it work...

**This is my smarty plugin:**

```
<?php
function smarty_function_alticerik($params, &$smarty) {
    if (!function_exists('alticerik')) {
        if (!function_exists('get_instance')) return "Can't get CI instance";
        $CI= &get_instance();
    }

    return $CI->IceriklerMod->liste($params['where']);
}      
?>
```

**And these are my jabber wocky TPL codes:**

```
{foreach item=alt from=alticerik|@alticerik(where="where ustid=$ustid")}
{$alt.id}
{/foreach}
```

I have searched and read all of the smarty help pages but I still have no idea that how can I make this codes work correctly...

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left. You may need to use a browser, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is that functions don't get called using that Smarty syntax.

What you're doing is sort of a mix between a function and a modifier.

Modifiers change a given input - for example, lower casing a string.

```
{$upperCaseWord|strtolower}
```

Functions take named parameters and usually do a bit more work such as creating a dropdown.

```
{html_options options=$arrayOfOptions selected=$selectedValue}
```

In your case, I'm guessing that you want to use a modifier since you look to be attempting to modify a value.  You can still pass options into those, but they aren't named and it gets fairly confusing quickly.  However, the code might be:

```
{foreach item=alt from=$alticerik|@alticerik:"where ustid=$ustid"}
     {$alt.id}
{/foreach}
```

Meanwhile your actual function looks like:

```
<?php
function smarty_modifier_alticerik($input, $whereString) {
    // Here, $input is the same as your $alticerik variable
    // and $whereString is just the string that comes after the colon.
    if (!function_exists('alticerik')) {
        if (!function_exists('get_instance')) return "Can't get CI instance";
        $CI= &get_instance();
    }

    return $CI->IceriklerMod->liste($whereString);
}      
?>
```

Note, however, that in your code, you don't end up using the value of $alticerik from your template, so it makes me wonder if you need a function instead.  I can't really know for sure unless I get what the alticerik plugin is supposed to do.

For more information on functions and modifiers, see the documentation here: [Smarty.net Function Documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl) and here: [Smarty.net Modifier Documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `$CI =& get_instance();` perhaps?

and what's not working? Any errors?

Comment: The point is that I can't call my personal smarty plugin (which is alticerik) in my TPL files... I need to call "alticerik" function and get the DB result array and then use smarty's foreach in my TPL file.